# Make page tab link to pdf

Tags: links, pdf

I'm sure this is ridiculously simple, and I'm just missing something very basic. I have a CV as a pdf. I'd like to have the tab that says CV open up that CV as a pdf. I do not want to embed it as a Google Doc or anything.

**EDIT:**
Including link to my site. http://adamgoodkind.com/. I'd like the "CV" tab to bring up the pdf.

Comment: Can you post a URL to your site and let us know where would you like to have that tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about menus and your theme uses the Menu API, then upload the PDF to a publicly accessible server-- doesn't have to to be the one your site uses-- then

1. go to Appearance -> Menus,
2. Navigate to a menu, or create one
3. find the "Links" dialogue,
4. input the URL and the link text
5. Save

Comment: For some reason, when I do that, the "Add to Menu" button stays greyed out. When I click it, it looks like it's processing, but then everything just disappears.

Comment: Do you have a menu created/selected?

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I needed to actually create a custom menu. I didn't realize I had never created one.